# MySQL - why limit varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL you have to set a limit if you are to use a varchar.
Does this limit only exist to make it less likely for devs to accidentally store too much data or is there any other reason (i.e. more effcient access) to set it to a low value?

Comment: @Strawberry He's asking why you have to declare a column to be `VARCHAR(length)` rather than just a generic `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VARCHAR` columns are represented in the database with a fixed-size length field and variable-length contents.

The database needs to know how many bytes to use for the hidden length field. If the length is less than 256 it uses 1 byte, if it's between 256 and 65535 it uses 2 bytes.

It could have been possible to use a length field that automatically expands as needed. But keeping it fixed-length makes things more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this came from the ablity to "jump" from one records to another, in memory. This may explain why the total amount of data of a record can't be more than 65535 bytes, so a "word".
But in order to know if your record isn't bigger than 65535 bytes, MySQL must know the size.

Notice also, we're talking here of "byte size" and not "number of char".
Meaning MySQL will take the value you set as varchar (number of char) but then multiply this by the size of a char, depending on the collation, to see if the whole record can fit into the 65536 byte limit.

Just create a table and add a field of type varchar(30000) with a ascibin collation. This will be OK. Now, edit this table, just setting collation to utf8.... And you'll see MyQL will not accept.